# Thread safe container for single object in c++

Tags: c++, thread-safety

Is there a c++ container (single writer, many reader) for storing a single value that is always read-/writeable (lockfree)? When reading getting an outdated version is fine.

I thought of something like that:

```
template <class T>
class Container {
    bool active = 0;
    T object[2];
public:
    void writeData(T t)
    {
        object[!active] = t;
        active = !active;
    }
    T readData()
    {
        return object[active];
    }
};
```

One Problem I thought of:

```
Read thread reads active = 0
Write thread happens (active = 1)
another Write thread starts and writes to 0
Read thread reads the data which is currently written to
```

Of cause active is not atomic, but since it is a bool and only one write thread happens at a time, both possible values are acceptable.

Comment: You need to consider what happens when the compiler optimises your code.  Code may be omitted as the compiler will not realise that values need to be re-read if they might have been updated in another thread.  You might never see an updated value if the compiler optimises to remove unnecessary reads (or writes).

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution but an idea of how this could be done:

Assuming that value you want to store is non-primitive type (otherwise just use `atomic`, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) then what you can do is use something like `atomic<Container*> current_container;` as a central-pointer-to-your-object. And in your `writer` on each update prepare new fully formed `Container` object with updated data and when its done set `current_container` to point to a new object.

Note that there is a few caveats in this approach:

- in writer, you can not immediately delete the old instances of `Container` after replacements because some of your readers might be still using it. If your Container's will be dynamically allocated then this might get tricky. You might want to use `std::shared_ptr` for `current_container` and `atomic_exchage` as means to change it value (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic)
- this approach will require writer to fully prepare a new version of `Container` for each update - this could be costly if `Container` is large and if its copying is expensive

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a ready-to-use implementation. But there's an effort to get such a facility into the C++ standard:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0561r3.html

The paper shows that, for full thread-safety and some form of reclamation, you have a rather complex problem to solve. In any case, the specification in the paper should help creating a correct implementation.